# Proof of a given Subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

I am trying to prove that: $(A∩B∩C)⊆(A∩B)$

Which is equal to: $x∈(A∩B∩C) \to x∈(A∩B)$

Taking the contra-positive we get: $x∉(A∩B) \to x∉(A∩B∩C)$

My question is can I do this: $x∈¬(A∩B) \to x∈¬(A∩B∩C)$

And then use De Morgan's Law: $x∈(¬A∪¬B) \to x∈(¬A∪¬B∪¬C)$

And if not, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: I suggest you remember that if you are dark, tall, *and* handsome, then you are certainly dark and tall.

Comment: As @ArturoMagidin comments, think about the _meaning_ of the claim, in words, rather than trying formal manipulations of the expressions.

Comment: commend to use latex for equations

Comment: Prove more generally (and more easily) that $D\cap C\subseteq D.$

Comment: Normally you take the contrapositive, when the contrapositive is easier to prove. Is that the case here? Your method is fine, but it's more work than is needed. What does it mean for x to be in the intersection of A,B,C , and what do we need to show is true for x to in A intersection B?

Comment: The definition of $A\cap B\cap C$ is $\{x : x \in A \text{ and }x \in B\text{ and }x \in C\}$. The definition of $A\cap B$ is $\{x : x \in A \text{ and }x \in B\}$.